# Auth0 integration with Apache Superset: Error Invalid login. Please try again

Tags: auth0, apache-superset

I have set up Apache Superset to authenticate with Auth0. Auth0 validation is successful but does not redirect to the welcome page. I get the error message: `"Invalid login. Please try again."`

I attached `custom_sso_security_manager.py` & `superset_config.py`. Is there any other files, any other modification required?

My Superset is running with Docker on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Docker Log:**

```
superset_app             | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): dev-xdvt19qd.us.auth0.com:443
superset_app             | DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://dev-xdvt19qd.us.auth0.com:443 "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
superset_app             | ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.views:Error returning OAuth user info: Invalid URL 'userinfo': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://userinfo?
```

**`custom_sso_security_manager.py`:**

```py
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('auth0_login')

class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):

    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None ):
        if provider == 'auth0':
            res = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('userinfo')
            print(res)
            if res.status != 200:
                logger.error('Failed to obtain user info: %s', res.data)
                return
            me = res.data
            logger.debug(" user_data: %s", me)
            prefix = 'Superset'
            return {
                'username' : me['email'],
                'name' : me['name'],
                'email' : me['email'],
                'first_name': me['given_name'],
                'last_name': me['family_name'],
            }
```

**`superset_config.py`:**

```py
ROW_LIMIT = 5000
SUPERSET_WORKERS = 4
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PORT = 8088
import os
import logging
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
#AUTH_OID, AUTH_REMOTE_USER, AUTH_DB,AUTH_LDAP, AUTH_OAUTH
from custom_sso_security_manager import CustomSsoSecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"
AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = 'http'
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
{
        'name':'auth0',
        'token_key': 'access_token',
        'icon':'fa-google',
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id': 'xxxxxxxyMs',
            'client_secret': 'xxxxxxr0UKg-ubX',
            'client_kwargs': {'scope': 'openid profile email',},
        'base_url': 'https://dev-x.us.auth0.com',
        'access_token_url': 'https://dev-x.us.auth0.com/oauth/token',
        'authorize_url': 'https://dev-x.us.auth0.com/authorize',
        'access_token_method': 'POST'
        }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code as below in(custom_sso_security_manager.py) and issue resolved.

```
class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
authoauthview = CustomOauthView
def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None ):
    if provider == 'auth0':
        res = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('base_url/userinfo')
        me = res.json()
        logger.info(" user_data: %s", me)

        prefix = 'Superset'
        return {
            'username' : me['email'],
            'name' : me['name'],
            'email' : me['email'],
            'first_name': me['email'],
            'last_name': me['name'],
        }
```

"base_url" needs to replace with User base url like this (https://sssssccvvv.us.auth0.com')

Answer (score 0):

instead of base_url, please use:

'api_base_url': 'https://{okta.domain}.okta.com/oauth2/v1/',