# Apache Superset and Auth0 returns "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Tags: oauth, auth0, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I'm trying to set up Superset with Auth0. I've found somewhat similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645248/apache-superset-and-auth0-returns-unexpected-keyword-argument-scope) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989348/auth0-integration-with-apache-superset-error-invalid-login-please-try-again?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I've set up the following configuration based on the first link above and trying to follow the Superset and [Flask-AppBuilder docs](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html):

```
    from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import (
        AUTH_OAUTH,
    )

    from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager

    import json
    import logging
    import string
    import random

    nonce = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase, k = 30))

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
    AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
    AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"

    AUTH0_URL = os.getenv('AUTH0_URL')
    AUTH0_CLIENT_KEY = os.getenv('AUTH0_CLIENT_KEY')
    AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET')

    OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
      { 'name':'auth0',
        'token_key':'access_token',
        'icon':'fa-at',
        'remote_app': {
            'api_base_url': AUTH0_URL,
            'client_id': AUTH0_CLIENT_KEY,
            'client_secret': AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
            'server_metadata_url': AUTH0_URL + '/.well-known/openid-configuration',
            'client_kwargs': {
                'scope': 'openid profile email'
            },
            'response_type': 'code token',
            'nonce': nonce,
        }
      }
    ]

    class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
        def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
            logger.debug('oauth2 provider: {0}'.format(provider))
            if provider == 'auth0':
                res = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get(AUTH0_URL + '/userinfo')
                logger.debug('response: {0}'.format(res))
                if res.raw.status != 200:
                    logger.error('Failed to obtain user info: %s', res.json())
                    return
                # user_info = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].parse_id_token(res)
                # logger.debug('user_info: {0}'.format(user_info))
                me = res.json()
                return {
                    'username' : me['email'],
                    'name' : me['name'],
                    'email' : me['email'],
                }

    CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager
```

The full error log message is:

```
2022-03-18 18:53:56,854:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.views:Error authorizing OAuth access token: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

NOTES:

- I can see an `access_token` parameter in the redirect url, so it *seems* to be working with Auth0 correctly.
- I don't see any of the debug lines in the `CustomSsoSecurityManager` being written, so my guess is that I have not correctly set that up (or my logging is not correctly configured).
- I've tried using both `Regular Web Application` and `Single Page Application` application types in Auth0, and both fail in the same way.

I would appreciate any help in understanding what I might be missing or what else I need to do to configure Auth0 to work with Superset.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work using the JSON Web Key Set endpoint provided by Auth0, look at this example and adapt it accordingly:

```
from jose import jwt
from requests import request
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager


class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    def request(self, url, method="GET", *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("headers", {})
        response = request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response

    def get_jwks(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request(url, *args, **kwargs).json()

    def get_oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        if provider == "auth0":
            id_token = response["id_token"]
            metadata = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].server_metadata
            jwks = self.get_jwks(metadata["jwks_uri"])
            audience = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].client_id
            payload = jwt.decode(
                id_token,
                jwks,
                algorithms=["RS256"],
                audience=audience,
                issuer=metadata["issuer"],
            )
            first_name, last_name = payload["name"].split(" ", 1)
            return {
                "email": payload["email"],
                "username": payload["email"],
                "first_name": first_name,
                "last_name": last_name,
            }
        return super().get_oauth_user_info(provider, response)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, and apologies for the delay in replying. I attempted to use your snippet, but my helm install fails with `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: post-upgrade hooks failed: timed out waiting for the condition`. I've tried uninstalling then re-installing, but I keep getting the same error. I tried adding `jose` and `python-jose` to the `bootstrapScript`, but the logs report the package cannot be found.

Comment: Specific error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jose'`

Comment: Just a small note: python-jose has to be installed